# ValueError: malformed string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api, unicode

I am working with an API which returns the following unicode as response:

```
    dd = u"""{"meta":{"request":{"granularity":"Weekly","main_domain_only":false,
"domain":"borivali.me",
    "country":"world"},"status":"Success",
"last_updated":"2016-05-09"},"bounce_rate":[{"date":"2016-04-12","bounce_rate":0.5},
    {"date":"2016-04-19","bounce_rate":0.13355382826388454},
{"date":"2016-04-26","bounce_rate":0.0},
    {"date":"2016-05-03","bounce_rate":0.23602940883106352}]}"""
```

I'm trying to parse this information in the following way:

```
ddd = ast.literal_eval(dd)
print ddd
```

However, I get the following error:

`ValueError: malformed string`

What seems to be wrong with my code?

PS: `dd` stores a unicode string and not a dictionary.

Comment: What is there to parse? `dd` is a dictionary, use it.

Comment: @DisplayName It is a unicode. Already mentioned that at the start of the post.

Comment: Show us [MCVE] - _unicode literal_ which is parsed, not Python dictionary literal.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming following definition is correct:

```
s = u"""{"meta":{"request":{"granularity":"Weekly","main_domain_only":false,
"domain":"borivali.me",
    "country":"world"},"status":"Success",
"last_updated":"2016-05-09"},"bounce_rate":[{"date":"2016-04-12","bounce_rate":0.5},
    {"date":"2016-04-19","bounce_rate":0.13355382826388454},
{"date":"2016-04-26","bounce_rate":0.0},
    {"date":"2016-05-03","bounce_rate":0.23602940883106352}]}"""
```

Given that declaration, `s` is JSON document and may be parsed to Python objects with `json` library.

```
import json
p = json.loads(s)
```

`ast` module is used to deserialise `repr` of Python objects, and `repr` does not equal JSON serialization in general case. Following relations holds (at least for simple Python types, well defined in JSON standard - lists, dicts and strings).

```
d == ast.literal_eval(repr(d))
d == json.loads(json.dumps(d))
```

Comment: To add to this, the contents of `s` are not valid Python (which you can see just by pasting them into a script and running it directly) because of the `false`, which in Python would be `False`. Without that `literal_eval` would work. But using `json` is definitely the correct thing to do.